# How to get last and first date of every week from predefined date table (oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have Table **D_date** in which all dates of a year, week number,quarter number etc attributes are defined. I just want to get first and last date of every week of year 2015.

**Sample D_date tabe attached.**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Use **ROW_NUMBER() OVER()** analytic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple min/max if I understand you right

```
SELECT calendar_year_nbr, week, min(actual_date),max(actual_date)
FROM D_date
GROUP BY calendar_year_nbr, week
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to get first and last date of every week of year 2015.

Since you have precomputed values already stored in the table, you could directly use **MIN** and **MAX** as aggregate functions along with **GROUP BY**.

For example,

```
SELECT MIN(actual_date) min_date,
      MAX(actual_date) max_date,
      calendar_week_nbr
FROM d_date
WHERE calendar_year_nbr = 2015
GROUP BY calendar_week_nbr
ORDER BY min_date;
```

Another way is to use **ROWNUM() OVER()** analytic function.